# part names of variable declaration

Tags: c#, c, variables, types

I am trying to extract debug information from a compiled C program with C#, and need to store the global variables.

If I have the variable:

```
const unsigned char * volatile MyVariable;
```

the name of the variable will be **MyVariable**, and the type is **unsigned char**. what will be **const** and **volatile**. Are they part of the type?

I have to represent a variable with a class and I am lost on how to construct it. This is how I have represented it right now:

```
public class MyVariable
{
     public string Name;
     public string Type;

     public bool IsArray;
     public bool IsPointer;
     public bool IsConstant;
     public bool IsVolatile;
     // etc...

     public int Size; // in bytes
}
```

Should I make `volatile` and `const` part of the type? What are they? Attributes?

### Edit

Sorry I think I did not explained my self correctly. **my question should have been how should I construct MyVariable class** I know what the const keyword does to a variable and also the volatile. I use the volatile keyword when I create a variable that will be accessed by multiple threads for example.

Anyways so based on the answers I should be constructing my class as:

```
public class MyVariable
{
     public string Name;
     public string Type;

     public string[] TypeQualifiers;

     public int Size; // in bytes
}
```

where TypeQualifiers will be an array of those keywords (type qualifiers).  Thanks a lot for the help.

Comment: what language are you trying to write for?  Clearly not C since you are using classes...

Comment: I am extracting the debug information from a compiled c program with c# and need to store the global variables.

Comment: `const` and `volatile` are type qualifiers. `MyVariable` is a volatile pointer to `const unsigned char`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`const` and `volatile` are both [*type qualifiers*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_syntax#Type_qualifiers), although they are completely independent.

The `const` keyword specifies that the object or variable cannot be changed within the code.

The `volatile` qualifier declares the data can have its value changed in ways outside the control or detection of the compiler, preventing the compiler from applying any optimizations on the code (such as storing the object's value in a register rather than the memory, where it may have changed).

A variable which is both `const` and `volatile` means that it is guaranteed not to be changed in the current code, but that does not mean that it cannot be changed externally.

---

**EDIT**: As a sidenote, `unsigned` is a type modifiers in C, just like `signed` and `long`.
I suggest that you also have independent type fields such as `IsSigned`, `IsUnsigned` and `IsLong` in addition to the type itself (`int`, `char`, etc...).

Comment: I agree. I will have int as the type and I will set the property isUnsigned=true in the class...

Answer (score 1):

Yout project will give you some trouble, since you are apparently not really familiar with C, and most importantly, do not have a good language reference at hand...

`const`, `volatile` and `restrict` are "type qualifiers". For example, `unsigned char` is an *unqualified* type. The qualifiers give the compiler additional hints on how to handle the memory. They can be attached in just about any combination.

Comment: DevSolar take a look at my edit. Thanks so much for the help. I guess I will implement the class like on my edit...

Answer (score 1):

Start by reading section 6.7 (Declarations) of latest online [C Standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf).

You're going to have a hard time capturing all the nuances of C declaration syntax in a flat data structure such as in your example.  The concept of "type" can get pretty complicated, such as

```
int *(*(*f[N])())[M];
```

where `f` has type "N-element array of pointers to functions returning pointers to M-element arrays of pointers to `int`".  You'll probably never see anything that obnoxious in real code, but it illustrates the difficulty of extracting type information from a declaration.

Comment: Wow. The dwarf info should contain all that info. That is a good point. I need to create a class that will enable to represent that...